# Using XGBoost to predict importance or percentage based on inputs

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

I am working on interpreting my XGBoost model. Take for example, the two datasets `trainInput` and `trainOutput` below, respectively:

```
df.trainInputs
    input1 input2 input3
0      1     0      0
1      1     1      0
2      0     1      1
..

df.trainOutputs
      output
0       1   
1       0
2       1
...
```

The user inputs have been one-hot encoded and the output data is a list of user output patterns. I am training my XGBoost model with these and then predicting based on another matrix of one-hot encoded user input data from another dataset. I am hoping to retrieve a percentage score for each element of the column, but upon running my model, am only receiving binary output. Is there something that I am missing in building my model? The relevant code:

```
df.predictInputs
    input1 input2 input3
0      1     1      0
1      1     0      0
2      1     0      1
..

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.fit(trainInputs, trainOutput)
y_pred = model.predict(predictOutput)
```

Comment: Why do you put `predictOutput` as argument of `model.predict`? Shouldn't it be something like `predictOutputs = model.predict(testInputs)`? Then you can compare you `predictOutputs` with real outputs to see the correct percentage.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part - I am using `predictInputs`. My concern is that the result of `predictOutputs` is returning binary and not percent, but I may be missing a step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the result probability (percentage score for each element), use `predict_proba` instead of `predict`.